# Japanese Text Normalization

Tags: 自然言語処理

テキストの正規化は、TTS（音声合成）およびASR（自動音声認識）システムの重要な部分です。[NeMo_text_processing](https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo-text-processing)のようないくつかのオープンソースのテキスト正規化プロジェクトがあります。ただし、これらのいくつかは日本語をサポートしていないようです。[Open JTalk](https://open-jtalk.sourceforge.net/)は数字の正規化を行っていますが、それだけは十分ではありません。日本語向けのプロジェクトや関連する文献はありますか？